# Gateway timeout for Https Functions proxied through Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

## Problem:

We are using Https Functions that are taking longer than 60 sec to respond (this is a necessary requirement for our use case and cannot be replaced with async execution). We configured the functions timeout, such that they succeed after e.g. 75 sec, as indicated by direct execution from Chrome or Postman through e.g. `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/test`.

We have also configured Hosting proxy to rewrite all requests for `/api` to these functions. However, when submitting identical requests through these "hosting" endpoints (e.g. `https://<project-id>.firebaseapp.com/api/test`), we receive a 504 (Gateway timeout) error after only 60 sec, both in Chrome and Postman. This suggests that the Hosting proxy itself times out *before* a function **succeeds** (**which** still happens, as indicated in Firebase Console log).

## Question:

Is it possible to set Hosting timeout to a higher value (e.g. 120 sec)?

## Possible solutions/workarounds:

- tried to set `Connection: keep-alive` and `Keep-Alive: timeout=120` headers in client requests, however that didn't seem to have any effect on the Hosting proxy; or maybe we're not doing it right.
- the only workaround for now is to not use rewrite rules, instead relying on the "direct" URLs (from `cloudfunctions.net`). However, that entails dealing with CORS in browser clients and more importantly, changing our URL resolution scheme and organization of functions' code (e.g. we cannot use a long path for each function, such as `/api/some/path/to/test`, because only the first part of that path, such as `api`, will be considered as the function name).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write your function in such a way as to maintain a persistent connection:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/networking#https_requests

```
const http = require('http');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const agent = new http.Agent({keepAlive: true});

exports.function = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    req = http.request({
        host: '',
        port: 80,
        path: '',
        method: 'GET',
        agent: agent,
    }, res => {
        let rawData = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', chunk => { rawData += chunk; });
        res.on('end', () => {
            response.status(200).send(`Data: ${rawData}`);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', e => {
        response.status(500).send(`Error: ${e.message}`);
    });
    req.end();
});
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the hosting itself, not cloud functions. Also doesn't that doc relate to accessing external APIs from a function, not calling the function's server itself?

Comment: @dinvlad the doc is a little unclear: "The optimized code snippet below shows how to maintain persistent connections instead of creating a new connection upon every function invocation."

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this very same problem with a Cloud Scheduler Job that hits my API endpoint (which is connected via Firebase Hosting). It takes around 80 seconds to complete.

But it seems that there is no workaround to this. At least not while using Firebase Hosting. Maybe you can hit the functions' URL directly instead of doing it through Firebase Hosting. But if those request are coming from the browser, you'd have to deal with configuring CORS.

**From:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

[image]

**Text version:**

> Note: Firebase Hosting is subject to a 60-second request timeout. Even if you configure your HTTPS function with a longer request timeout, you'll still receive an HTTPS status code 504 (request timeout) if your function requires more than 60 seconds to run. To support dynamic content that requires longer compute time, consider using an App Engine flexible environment.

Comment: that's correct - we had to switch to direct requests with CORS as well :-/ At least, this is documented behavior now..